# Change the Height of the div according to the text in it without javascript

Tags: html, css

How can i change the height of my div according to the text inside it . when i check for the responsiveness the text snaps out of the div . `Display : inline-block` does not work . i want to adjust height instead of making overflow hidden

[image]

My div is inside a row .

```
          <div class="row pd-md-x-15 pd-xs-x-15">
              <div class="pd-t-20 wer bd-t wd-100p">
                <a href=""></a>
                the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog  
              </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Don't give the `div` a fixed height?

Comment: You did not share your div's CSS... therefore we cannot help

Comment: Well of course it won't. Fixed height means fixed height. If you fix the height, it has no ability to stretch according to its contents, as dictated by the screen size. Simply remove the fixed height.

Comment: @Haroon nasir created a code snippet of your code. please check and tell us what is not working

Comment: use col-*-* classes inside the row to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

Check if your div (or it's container) has defined height or max-height, if so then remove or override them with:

```
height: auto;
max-height: none;
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use **inline CSS** to make the div height automated to your text

```
      <div class="row pd-md-x-15 pd-xs-x-15" style="height:auto;">
          <div class="pd-t-20 wer bd-t wd-100p">
            <a href=""></a>
            the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog  
          </div>
      </div>
```